# Developing eBay or AppStore like application in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am new to the iPhone application development. I am planing to develop a new application for iPhone. Which will look similar to the AppStore application in iPhone but the functionality is different.

I would like to get few information regarding the development of this kind of application.

1. I want to save some products information in a central database.- is there any db available to store application based information. Or do we need to have our own db servers and use it.
2. If the db servers are not available can we develop a webservice application and develop a client application for iPhone and can use the web service- is it possible?
3. Which is the best option to develop an application like AppStore or eBay apart from the above mentioned ideas.

Please help.

**UPDATE**

- Appstore like application means - look and feel is like AppStore.
- eBay like application means- functionality is like eBay.

I will be updating few products information in a db and this application can list all those product information and registered users can buy those products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you can use SQLite or CoreData on the phone, but I would go with
   the option number
2. Yes you can, use JSON to be fast with a
   simple restfull service will do.
3. This would be the best way.

But what do you mean by AppStore application, because you can not install apps via your own app using the official SDK.

Comment: If I use SQLite it will save the data on the phone then the user will not be able to share the data with other users. I want to store the data in a central place so all the users can view it.

Comment: Then you will need to create a webservice to do this for you.

Comment: You need to have the webservices for this app to make the data available globally to all users and you can also use database to store some parts of data to show on devices when there is no net access.That depends upon you